# Not getting fields to post data in Django REST framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Perfoming a crud api rest in django rest framwork, i created class based views. But when i run my app in browse, I am not getting forms to post data. When i scroll down getting media type and content option not my model fields.

There is my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from djongo import models as djongo_models
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from api.enums import Status, UserRole

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The email is required')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('role', UserRole.ADMIN)
        return self.create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
    
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    mongo_id = djongo_models.ObjectIdField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.mongo_id:
            self.mongo_id = ObjectId()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, default='')
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, default='')

    password = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False,)

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)

    def check_password(self, raw_password):
        return check_password(raw_password, self.password)

    phone_number = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+\d{1,3}\s\d{6, 14}$', message='Insert a valid phone number and it\'s country code')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=[(role, role.value) for role in UserRole],)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=[(tag, tag.value) for tag in Status])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'phone_number', 'birth_date', 'role', 'status']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import User
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

class UserRegistrationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'phone_number',
            'birth_date',
            'role',
            'status',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
            lastname=validated_data['lastname'],
            phone_number=validated_data['phone_number'],
            birth_date=validated_data['birth_date'],
            role=validated_data['role'],
            status=validated_data['status'],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'name',
            'lastname',
            'password',
            'phone_number',
            'email',
            'birth_date',
            'role',
            'status',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'id',
            'mongo_id',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'deleted'
        )

    def get_token(self, obj):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        token = {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        }
        return token
```

And views.py:

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

from api.models import User
from api.serializers import UserSerializer, UserRegistrationsSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class UserRegister(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserRegistrationsSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            serializer = UserSerializer(user)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
class UserLogin(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email_or_username = request.data.get('email_or_username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, email=email_or_username, password=password)
        if not user is None:
            serializer = UserSerializer(user)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return JsonResponse({'Detail': 'Invalid Credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    
class UserList(ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        users = User.objects.all()
        users_serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(users_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
class UserDetail(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'The User does not exists'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.deleted = True
        user.save()
        return JsonResponse(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

class DeletedUsers(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    queryset = User.objects.filter(deleted=True)
```

And when i go to the post request user register:

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNOEY.png)

Comment: This screenshot is of a get request

Comment: @delighted.rock so??